# Javascript fires twice Wordpress admin metabox

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I added a inline Javascript code to my metabox callback function.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box( 'catalog-item', 'Gegevens', 'catalog_details_callback', 'catalog', 'advanced' );
});

function catalog_details_callback( $post ) {
    <input type="text" class="price" name="price" id="price"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('price').onfocusout = function() {
        var regex = /^(\d+[,]+\d{2})$/;
        if (regex.test(this.value) == false ) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/([^(\d|,)]|,{2})/g, "");
        }
        var before = this.value.replace(",", ".");
        var roundoff = parseFloat(before).toFixed(2);
        var after = roundoff.replace(".", ",");
        alert(after);
    }
    </script>
}
```

If the function is triggered the function fires the alert twice.
Does anybody know how I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with Wordpress.
This works for me

```
    const price_field = document.getElementById('price');
    price_field.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
        var regex = /^(\d+[,]+\d{2})$/;
        if (regex.test(price_field.value) == false ) {
            this.value = price_field.value.replace(/([^(\d|,)]|,{2})/g, "");
        }
        var before = price_field.value.replace(",", ".");
        var roundoff = parseFloat(before).toFixed(2);
        var after = roundoff.replace(".", ",");
        price_field.value = after;
        alert(after);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reason for this:

1. Please check if you have multiple event listeners. If so, try to check your condition. understand about event listeners here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event
2. onfocusout bubbles, means if you have any event written on parent as well as child then both gets called. try to add

```
 document.getElementById('price').onfocusout = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        var regex = /^(\d+[,]+\d{2})$/;
        if (regex.test(this.value) == false ) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/([^(\d|,)]|,{2})/g, "");
        }
        var before = this.value.replace(",", ".");
        var roundoff = parseFloat(before).toFixed(2);
        var after = roundoff.replace(".", ",");
        alert(after);
    }
```

3. If still issue persists then try to add the debugger in the function can check the call trace in google developers console.